# Create Intended UI Behavior While Also Not Getting Breaking Constraints Warnings

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, autolayout, constraints

I have a height constraint for a horizontal stackView within a UIView that I change based on the content of a view. If the text of a label in the stackView is beyond a certain size, the constraint moves to 116.33, otherwise it is 96. This horizontal stackView is pinned to the top of this UIView.

At runtime, I get a warning of this constraint being broken, but I get the intended operation:

[image]

[image]

If I remove the constraint "Horizontal Stack View.top = top", no warnings occur, but I don't get the intended operation:

[image]

I have tried commensurately changing the height of the UIView via locationView.frame.size.height as well as by adding another constraint to the view, specifically, and adjusting that in the same way I adjust the stackView height constraint, but the resulting behavior is essentially the same.

This is the document outline:

[image]

How can I get the intended effect, and also make XCode happy?

Comment: The best way to avoid issues with constraints is to not work with them at all. I'm sure you've spent plenty of time so far messing with your view here, but It will take a lot less time to do the math and set up frames programmatically and create events when the frame should change.

Comment: What if you lower the priority on the Stackview height constraint = 96 to less than1000?

Comment: You could also try changing Stackview height == 96 constraint to Stackview height >= 96.

Comment: @vacawama If I set the priority lower than 1000, the warnings disappear but the stackView height doesn't change. Doing the latter has the same effect and same warnings. Interestingly, I just noted that the warnings come after the first time the height constraint is changed, but not any time after that. Could that be a clue?

Comment: Which height constraint are you changing between 96 and 116.33?

Comment: It is the height of the horizontal stackView inside the UIView, which holds internal stackViews, labels, and the image

Comment: It appears you have a constraint on the view itself which is set to 116.33.  Why not let the height of the horizontal stackView set the height of the view.  Try removing the constraint for the view's height == 116.33.

Comment: Well it does look like I actually constrained the UIView rather than the horizontal stackView. Constraining the stackView instead reduced the number of the warnings but still has the same complaints. By the way, I've updated my question to show the document outline. Also, I don't have any height constraint on the view.

Comment: Update your warnings output above to match the constraints set in the document outline.

Comment: @vacawama Done.

Comment: @Pigpocket Looks like one of the height constraints needs to be a >= or removed completely and let the intrinsic height of your stackview determine the height. I'd suggest hitting pause on your debugging and entering the view hierarchy debugger. See this link: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/debugging_with_xcode/chapters/special_debugging_workflows.html

Comment: Your stack views have aligned top and bottoms, but one has a height constraint of 96 and the other has a height constraint of >= 136.  Both can't be satisfied.  Get rid of one of them.

Comment: Yes! Thanks @vacawama. You and Sandy are both correct. I actually had the height of my image locked at 96. This needs to expand in height as well. XCode was smart enough to just do this for me, but was also telling me I was doing it wrong. I have some experience with the view hierarchy debugger and tried using this but wasn't able to figure it out that way. I also tried printing out the instance variable numbers in the lldb, but the feedback is kind of cryptic. I'll have to work on that more. Thanks for all of your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how I read your 4 conflicting constraints:

1. Horizontal StackView height is 96.
2. The Horizontal StackView and Vertical StackView are aligned at their tops.
3. The Horizontal StackView and Vertical StackView are aligned at their bottoms.
4. Vertical StackView height is >= 136.

So the heights of the StackViews are the same because of the alignment of their tops and bottoms.  But they each have their own constraint setting their height.

I suggest getting rid of one of the StackView height constraints.